# Binding to complex object list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, model-binding

I have Entity model in mvc application. I have two tables:

Engine: Id, Name, Parts

Part: Id, EngineId, Name, Price

There is one to many relation between these two tables.

In the view:

```
@model Engine

<input type="hidden" name="Id" value="@Model.Id" />
<input type="text" name="Name" value="@Model.Name" />

@for(var part in Model.Parts)
{
    <input type="hidden" name="Parts.Index" value="@guide" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Parts[@guide].Id" value="@part.Id" />
    <input type="text" name="Parts[@guide].Name" value="@part.Name" />
    <input type="text" name="Parts[@guide].Price" value="@part.Price" />
}
```

In Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var model = context.Engines.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == id);
    return View("Engine", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
{
    var model = context.Engines.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == id);
    UpdateModel(model);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I'm adding and removing parts on the fly. When I post, I have list of Parts in model.Parts. They all have entity state added. I want that All Parts that have Id to have EntityState.Modified and those that are deleted must have EntityState.Deleted and added objects should have EntityState.Added. Is it possible? (EF version 4.0)

Answer (score 1):

Default binder know nothing about EF states. You can create new model binder for Engine class and set state there manually.

Comment: You can start from here (http://brendan.enrick.com/post/Custom-Model-Binders-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx) or here (http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-aspnet-mvc-model-binder-for.html)